# How to display same curl output on ansible?

Tags: rest, curl, ansible

I have curl(and rest api) command for oracle enterprise manager IaaS and would like to generate same output when using ansible for same requests (http get). In my test environment however ansible doesn't display proper output. Please see my test script and output and any comments would be really appreciated.

---

```
## curl --insecure -X GET -u osc_anz_admin:welcome1 myurl_here
{
  "uri" : "/em/cloud/iaas/server/byrequest/142" ,
  "status" : "DELETED" ,
  "canonicalLink" : "/em/websvcs/restful/extws/cloudservices/service/v0/ssa/em/cloud/iaas/server/byrequest/142"
}
```

---

```
## cat showvmstatus.yml
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: show vm status
    uri:
      url: myurl_here
      method: GET
      return_contents: yes
      user: osc_anz_admin
      password: welcome1
      validate_certs: no
      force_basic_auth: yes
    register: showvmstatus
  - name: show list
    debug: var=showvmstatus
```

---

```
## ansible-playbook showvmstatus.yml 

PLAY [localhost] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [show vm status] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [show list] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "showvmstatus": {
        "changed": false, 
        "connection": "close", 
        "content_language": "en,en-us", 
        "content_type": "application/oracle.com.cloud.common.VM+json; charset=utf-8", 
        "date": "Fri, 29 Sep 2017 05:22:06 GMT", 
        "location": "https://em13-test.gdn.aus.osc:7803?status,uri/em/cloud/iaas/server/byrequest/142", 
        "msg": "OK (unknown bytes)", 
        "redirected": false, 
        "server": "Oracle-HTTP-Server-12c", 
        "set_cookie": "ORA_SMP_EM_AUTH_-2918986201179331800=7oDMFbBgPTaoYai-V8wrdJcyMIfzMxomyg3XKocxrlRRx49cYn-z!-989316618; path=/em; secure; HttpOnly", 
        "status": 200, 
        "transfer_encoding": "chunked", 
        "url": "https://em13-test.gdn.aus.osc:7803/em/cloud/iaas/server/byrequest/142?status,uri", 
        "x_oracle_dms_ecid": "005M^oohrB28pmNMuIQ5UH00014L0002Z^", 
        "x_orcl_emoa": "true", 
        "x_specification_version": "10001"
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
##
```

---

As you can see above, no vm details displayed at all from ansible output.

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo in `return_contents: yes` – should be `return_content: yes`.

Comment: It works now with return_content: yes. Thanks a lot!